# Minified function in Javascript does not work but works when sourcemap enabled

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript function that compiles and runs:

```
statusParser = callback => (event) = {
    try {  
        let data = event.data;
        let message = JSON.parse(data).message;
        callback(message);
    } catch (exception) {
        //log
    }
}
```

I invoke this like this:

```
let messageHandler = statusParser(viewEventHandler);
```

However, after minification, the callback that exists in statusParser is another function and causes an exception with "call undefined". If I run the code using eval-source-map setting in my gulpfile the code will work successfully. If I run the code in browser console it also works. I've also looked through the minified file and can see that the viewEventHandler function or any function I pass in does exist. Is there something incorrect in currying the function this way that would cause minify to break?

Comment: You probably passed in an extra option value (i.e., `--toplevel`) to the minifier. What minifier are you using and what options are you passing to it?

Comment: The project does not configure the minifier in any special way. We set mode to production and I believe it uses the default values for TerserPlugin https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/.

Comment: Then what build tool are you using?

Comment: We are using Webpack along with Gulp.